# ASP NET ET INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hola amigos tengo la siguiente cuestion, quiero hacert un `inner join` de algunas tablas , pero hasta donde he tenido que hacer queries con **EF** , normalmente los hago así.

```
using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            var user = db.AspNetUsers.ToList<AspNetUsers>().Where(u => u.Id.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();

            return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }}
```

Y esto solo me permite llamar datos de una tabla, el query que quiero ejecutar es aslgo como esto.

```
select AspNetUsers.Id,email,AspNetUserRoles.RoleId,AspNetRoles.Name from AspNetUsers 
inner join AspNetUserRoles
on AspNetUsers.Id = AspNetUserRoles.UserId
inner join AspNetRoles
on AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId
where AspNetUsers.Id = 'miid'
```

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer este query o si puedo meter todo en un **Native SQL** la cuestion con esta opción es el modelo no sé con un modelo simple puedo igual hacer el query, más bien devolver la respuesta.

Comment: Todavía no le has dedicado tiempo a los enlaces que te pasé, ¿verdad? o ¿me equivoco?

Comment: No se mi fred, quiza si, pero tengo mucha chamba creeme que no pregunto TODO solo aquello que me urge para avanzar

Comment: No digo que esté mal preguntar, todo lo contrario, que una sola persona lance una pregunta, representa la voz de cientos y quizás miles de personas que les ha pasado lo mismo y que por algún motivo han mantenido silencio. Bueno, te dejo esto de tarea obligatoria: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/ ahí ve a qué actividades les restas tiempo para crear espacio (dormir media hora menos es un sacrificio enorme para muchos) para que revises este sitio, el contenido es buenísimo. Buenas vibras hermano lml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este tipo de consultas como regresas datos mezclados no es recomendable regresar un objeto anónimo, si no que declares un objeto que contenga toda la información que necesitas. 
Este objeto puede ser una clase y le llamaremos *[ViewModel](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo%E2%80%93vista%E2%80%93modelo_de_vista)* para pasar los datos a esta propiedad.

```
public class UsuariosViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
using(var db = new DbEnt())
{
    var query = from u in db.AspNetUsers
                join ur in db.AspNetUserRoles on u.Id equals r.UserId
                join r in db.AspNetRoles on r.Id equals ur.RoleId
                where u.Id == "ID"
                select new UsuariosViewModel { 
                    Id = u.Id, 
                    Email = u.Email, 
                    RoleId = r.RoleId, 
                    RoleName = r.Name };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando linq seria muy similar a tu consulta original

ejemplo:

```
try{
    DBEnt context = new DBEnt();//este seria tu instancia al contexto de tu base de datos
    var user = (from AspNetUsers in context.AspNetUsers
    join AspNetUserRoles in context.AspNetUserRoles on AspNetUserRoles.Id equals AspNetUsers.UserId   
    join AspNetRoles in context.AspNetRoles on AspNetUserRoles.Id equals AspNetRoles.RoleId
    where AspNetUsers.Id == 'miid'
    select new{
        Id=AspNetUsers.Id
        ,email=AspNetUsers.email
        ,RoleId=AspNetUserRoles.RoleId
        ,Name=AspNetRoles.Name
    }).ToList();
    return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
} catch (Exception ex)
{
   return BadRequest(ex.Message);
}
```